# Rendering random ordered Contenful data in Middleman

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, middleman, contentful

Stack overflow

I’m having a noob problem trying to figure out how to print some YML data in a ‘structured random order’. What I mean by that is that I’m using Contenful CMS to order content in a lookbook (https://www.contentful.com/blog/2015/09/10/creating-a-digital-lookbook/)
kind of fashion.

[image: Drag and drop CMS interface]
*I can drag and drop blocks from here, which will change the order for the YML*

The content editors can have the option to drag and drop the order of how the modules are shown. So the order of the YML data will always be different.

A quick mockup of what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is currently how the data looks

```
:caseModules:
- :id: 2sY3tXCqSIcIM2IUgqCCgG
  :quoteBody: Either you run the day or you day runs you
  :quoteOriginName: Ghandi
  :quoteDate: !ruby/object:DateTime 2017-03-23 00:00:00.000000000 Z
- :id: 2qpSXdyiqg8iQucGoQweio
  :caseImage:
    :title: Test image title
    :description: Test image description
    :url: "//images.contentful.com/d65nu5c5ibm8/3l2tizTPRSACEIUK0OugUi/65a718dfa621cb6d1d384251ef83a787/account.png"
  :caseImageName: Test image title
  :caseImageCaption: This test image is a nice example of how we want to showcase
    images on the page
- :id: 3HaLvYSEs86ACoqMYE0QSk
  :header: Header
  :body: "There are previous versions because you haven't made changes to this entry
    yet. As soon as you publish changes, you'll be able to compare different versions.\n\n"
- :id: 6HASpa0o3SkyMK4gYgIq8W
  :quoteBody: This is another quote
  :quoteOriginName: Sebastian Graz
  :quoteDate: !ruby/object:DateTime 2019-01-19 00:00:00.000000000 Z
- :id: 3D6Gx2qphK6qAI2qyYGcwK
  :caseImage:
    :title: king-fisher
    :description: With King Fisher we managed to create an unique experience using
      Spindrift Site Builder
    :url: "//images.contentful.com/d65nu5c5ibm8/5kCjQiyCv6m00m0m46UWi4/ce4ab4cdc8ade1fd63f3e564def42e45/king-fisher.png"
  :caseImageName: King Fisher case image name
  :caseImageCaption: King fisher image caption
```

Im using .erb to print the data like so:

```
  <% data.site.container.each do | _, project| %>
    <%= project['caseModules']%>
  <% end %>
```

Which gives me this on the front-end.

```
[# quoteOriginName="Ghandi">, # caseImageCaption="This test image is a nice example of how we want to showcase images on the page" caseImageName="Test image title" id="2qpSXdyiqg8iQucGoQweio">, #, # quoteOriginName="Sebastian Graz">, # caseImageCaption="King fisher image caption" caseImageName="King Fisher case image name" id="3D6Gx2qphK6qAI2qyYGcwK">]
```

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
  <% data.site.container.each do | _, project| %>
    <% project['caseModules'].each do | image | %>
       <%= image['caseImage']['url']%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

But I get the error: `` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass ``

So I'm wondering if anyone can give me some pointer on what I'm doing wrong. Should I be using a switch case to render the different block? Am I doing something wrong in the `<%= image['caseImage']['url']%>`
 Syntax that it doesn't work?

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:

I ended up using `has_key?` and it worked.

```
  <% data.site.container.each do | id, container| %>
    <% container.caseModules.each do | caseModules | %>

       <% if caseModules.has_key?("caseImage") && caseModules["caseImage"]%>
          <img src="<%= caseModules.caseImage['url'] %>" alt="" />
       <% end %>

       <% if caseModules.has_key?("quoteBody") && caseModules["quoteBody"]%>
          <%= caseModules.quoteBody %>
       <% end %>

       <% if caseModules.has_key?("body") && caseModules["body"]%>
          <%= caseModules.body %>
       <% end %>


    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the key in the YAML file is a Symbol and not a String, replace it with either `project[:caseModules]` or `project.caseModules` any of the two will work just as expected.

Comment: HI David, thanks for looking into my issue. That returns a hash which contain the following information: 

`<middleman::util::enhancedhash description="Test image description" title="Test image title" url="//images.contentful.com/d65nu5c5ibm8/3l2tizTPRSACEIUK0OugUi/65a718dfa621cb6d1d384251ef83a787/account.png">`

How do I access the url and load the image?

Comment: `image.caseImage['url']` Gives me undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Same as the previous reply, either `caseImage[:url]` or `caseImage.url`. But looks like `caseImage`  is `nil` for one or more of your entries. If that's the case, then you should check for `nil` values or use `Hash#fetch` which allows to provide a default value if the key was not found.

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere. So from my understanding, the error is being surfaced because not all blocks have an image. Can you point me to how I would use something like Hash#fetch in this instance? Thank you!

Comment: `caseImage.fetch(:url, "/images/placeholder.png")` should work (of course you should have a placeholder image, or something alike). Or you can replace that with anything else that you need.
Other possibility is a `nil` check and not rendering anything, like `if caseImage.url.nil? #...`

Comment: Hi David, thanks again for checking in! I managed to solve the issue by using `has_key?` Check the edit on my question :)